# Finding the K closest points of a vector to a separate point in Rstudio

Tags: r

Say I have a vector X consisting of points such as (1,4,5,6,3,2,5,7,8,44,3,7)
and I need I want to find the K=2 points of that are closest to 6.4 meaning 6 and 7 is there a function in are that does that and if not what is the best way to do that in R?

Comment: `x[order(abs(x-6.4))][1:2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a function then,

```
fun1 <- function(vec, val, k){
            vec[order(abs(vec-val))][seq_len(k)]
           }

fun1(x, 6.4, 2)
#[1] 6 7
fun1(x, 6.4, 3)
#[1] 6 7 7
fun1(x, 5, 4)
#[1] 5 5 4 6
```

To get unique values then add `unique`,

```
fun1 <- function(vec, val, k){
          unique(vec[order(abs(vec-val))])[seq_len(k)]
          }
fun1(x, 6.4, 3)
#[1] 6 7 5
```

Comment: Always better to use `seq_len(k)` instead of `1:k`.

Comment: I did not know that (that it was better). Thanks

Comment: It's safer since it prevents nasty surprises such as `1:0`.